# Cascading specific windows in a MFC MDI application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

A MDIParent Wnd has many MDIchild Wnds, and also few child dialogs.

Dialogs are created this way ---
  CAutoDlg *pDlg = new CAutoDlg;
  pDlg->Create(IDD_AUTOCARD,this);

I want to cascade only a specific type of dialogs, say dialogs of CAutoDlg type only.

If i give MDICascade() it cascades all the child windows and dialogs under the MDIFrame.
Is there any other un-conventional way other than calling SetWindowPos for each dialog, based on the position of the previous dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. You can have collection of `CAutoDlg` into some container. Using that container call appropriate function to cascade. You may use the `CAutoDlg`'s constructor to add dialog object into that container, and use destructor to remove dialog reference from container.